# How can I parse this json string from an AJAX success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, json-deserialization

Can someone please help with parsing some data from a json string. Here is the JSON data:

```
data = "{\"centerLatitude\":-41.22766,\"centerLongitude\":174.812761,\"mapTypeId\":\"google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP\",\"zoom\":18}"
```

In my AJAX code, I have the following code:

```
success: function (mapDetailsData) {
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(mapDetailsData);
    alert(data.centerLatitude);
    alert(data.centerLongitude);
}
```

I am getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

If I specify the JSON data as follows:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{\"centerLatitude\":-41.22766,\"centerLongitude\":174.812761,\"mapTypeId\":\"google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP\",\"zoom\":18}');
alert(data.centerLatitude);
alert(data.centerLongitude);
```

The `alert` displays the correct data.

How do I need to write the ajax code to display the correct values of `centerLatitude` and `centerLongitude`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `mapDetailsData` is already in JSON format and you don't need `jQuery.parseJSON`

Comment: JSON.parse succeeds for me for the original data string.

Comment: the problem seems to be that you are echoing the results of a query to a json like string  in the php instead of json_encoding the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you set the `datatype` parameter to `json` (or leave it at the default setting and it recognises the JSON format by itself) then jQuery will automatically deserialise the response for you. The error you see is normally an indication that you are trying to parse twice. Try this:

```
success: function (mapDetailsData) {
    alert(mapDetailsData.centerLatitude);
    alert(mapDetailsData.centerLongitude);
}
```